# IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 //Python (jupyter notebook)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, index-error

While trying to solve a system of nonlinear equations, I get an error message for this code as
"IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1". I am quite new to python and therefore I am not able to figure out where is the mistake.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import math


def equations(vars):
    x1 =vars[0]
    x2=vars[1]
    lambda1_L=vars[2]
    lambda2_L=vars[3]
    lambda1_U=vars[4]
    lambda2_U=vars[5]
    mu1=vars[6]
    mu2=vars[7]
    mu3=vars[8]
    mu4=vars[9]
    mu5=vars[10]
    mu6=vars[11]
    mu7=vars[12]
    mu8=vars[13]
    W1 =vars[14] 
    sigma_p= math.sqrt(0.028573*x1*x1+0.03129*x2*x2+0.020231*x1*x2)
    A= (0.028573*x1+0.010115*x2)/sigma_p
    B= (0.03129*x2+0.010115*x1)/sigma_p
    eqn1=292.7182*lambda1_L+(2.25*A-0.025926)*lambda2_L + 446.444*lambda1_U+(2.25*A-0.040535)*lambda2_U-446.444*mu1-0.405858*mu2+(2*A-0.057146*x1-0.020231*x2)*mu3+mu4-mu5+mu6
    eqn2= 272.9655*lambda1_L+(2.25*B-0.03633)*lambda2_L+513.4587*lambda1_U+(2.25*B-0.051024)*lambda2_U-513.4587*mu1-0.466781*mu2+(2*B-0.06258*x2-0.020231*x1)*mu3+mu4-mu7+mu8
    eqn3=mu1*(W1-446.444*x1-513.4587*x2-33)
    eqn4=mu2*(0.13-0.405858*x1-0.466781*x2)    
    eqn5=mu3*(x1+x2-1)
    eqn6=mu5*(0.03-x1)
    eqn7=mu6*(x1-0.38)
    eqn8=mu7*(0.05-x2)
    eqn9=mu8*(x2-0.42)
    return [eqn1, eqn2, eqn3,eqn4,eqn5,eqn6,eqn7,eqn8,eqn9]
    

ans=  optimize.fsolve(equations, vars)

print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

`vars` is a reserved word for python. The details are found here at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars. `Return the __dict__ attribute for a module, class, instance, or any other object with a __dict__ attribute.` I suggest you change the word `vars` to `variables` and provide "variables" or another name except reserved words for it.

```
def equations(variables):
    x1 =variables[0]
    x2=variables[1]
    lambda1_L=variables[2]
    lambda2_L=variables[3]
    lambda1_U=variables[4]
    lambda2_U=variables[5]
    mu1=variables[6]
    mu2=variables[7]
    mu3=variables[8]
    mu4=variables[9]
    mu5=variables[10]
    mu6=variables[11]
    mu7=variables[12]
    mu8=variables[13]
    W1 =variables[14] 
    sigma_p= math.sqrt(0.028573*x1*x1+0.03129*x2*x2+0.020231*x1*x2)
    A= (0.028573*x1+0.010115*x2)/sigma_p
    B= (0.03129*x2+0.010115*x1)/sigma_p
    eqn1=292.7182*lambda1_L+(2.25*A-0.025926)*lambda2_L + 446.444*lambda1_U+(2.25*A-0.040535)*lambda2_U-446.444*mu1-0.405858*mu2+(2*A-0.057146*x1-0.020231*x2)*mu3+mu4-mu5+mu6
    eqn2= 272.9655*lambda1_L+(2.25*B-0.03633)*lambda2_L+513.4587*lambda1_U+(2.25*B-0.051024)*lambda2_U-513.4587*mu1-0.466781*mu2+(2*B-0.06258*x2-0.020231*x1)*mu3+mu4-mu7+mu8
    eqn3=mu1*(W1-446.444*x1-513.4587*x2-33)
    eqn4=mu2*(0.13-0.405858*x1-0.466781*x2)    
    eqn5=mu3*(x1+x2-1)
    eqn6=mu5*(0.03-x1)
    eqn7=mu6*(x1-0.38)
    eqn8=mu7*(0.05-x2)
    eqn9=mu8*(x2-0.42)
    return [eqn1, eqn2, eqn3,eqn4,eqn5,eqn6,eqn7,eqn8,eqn9]
    
variables = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

ans=  optimize.fsolve(equations, variables)

print(ans)
```

While using the variables from posted I get:

> TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'equations'.Shape should be (15,) but it is (9,).

So please tune your input where needed.